# Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0 and failed to linking resources

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to add firebase authentication to my app but when adding

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

it says

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

i also tried with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'`
then it says

> failed linking references

Comment: can you please add your project level gradle file @Sandan Sermeera

Comment: do you have two versions here firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'  , use one of them and update if necessary, Android Studio import this two when you try to add Firebase from there

Answer (score 0):

into your root-level build.gradle put this

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

and in your app-level build.gradle file in dependancies section put this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having this in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
allprojects {
   repositories {
       google() 
   }
}
```

You must have the following `build.gradle` for the app level:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It is important that you have both the **`firebase-core` dependency** and `firebase-auth`. Additionally, you must have the **`plugin` for google services** underneath the dependecies section.